# Does the usage of Parser make sense?

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming

I have the following text and would like to transform into a data structure.

The text is:

```
pcp-action:MESSAGE\npcp-channel:apc\:///\npcp-body-type:text\nPUBLIC:THISPK\nTOPIC:SEND\n\nHello Foo
```

I would like to know, if it makes sense to use Parser for it. To be honestly, I can not see the sense to use `Parser` in this case, because the structure is not in `BNF` like for example `JSON` and it is not recursively enumerable.

When does it make sense to transform a text with `Parser` into a data structure?

**Update**

I forget to mention the text above is based on the following description, that is written here https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/27/specification-of-the-push-channel-protocol-pcp/.

It looks like, it is based on a grammar.

Comment: Why do you think that parsers should only be used on recursively enumerable BNF grammars?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I just guess. When I look at examples, it always shows a text, that is always recursively enumerable.

Comment: What kind of data structure are you looking for? And what variety do you expect in the input text?

Comment: Transforming texts into data structures is by definition *parsing*. Are you talking about a particular package's `Parser`?

Comment: This is a single string, not a language; the property "recursively enumerable" doesn't type-check. If you have just a single string, then you can just make a single value that has what you need from that string. If you have a collection of strings, then you must describe it better than just "here's one element of the collection". (I don't immediately see what makes you think such a collection would obviously not be recursively enumerable. That outcome would kind of surprise me.)

Comment: I would like to transform into `data Pcp = Pcp { publicKey :: String  , event :: String, body :: String `

Comment: The protocol is describing on https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/27/specification-of-the-push-channel-protocol-pcp/. And yes it is a grammar.

Comment: Then it is both defined by a BNF grammar and recursively enumerable and I am even more confused by your question.

Comment: @zero_coding Then yes a parser definitely makes sense

Comment: I can not see, that it is a BNF grammar and recursively enumerable.

Comment: You literally just posted a link to the BNF grammar.

Comment: @zero_coding It's right there in the page you linked: "*A Push Channel Protocol  (PCP) message can be more formally described using the Backus-Naur Form grammar. Figure 1 shows the structure of a PCP message.*" Of course, posting the grammar as a GIF image, not text, is a horrible practice.

Comment: If it can be described by a BNF grammar then it is recursively enumerable.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I can not see, that it is recursively enumerable.

Comment: BNF grammars describe context-free languages. All context-free languages are recursively enumerable. Therefore, if it is described by a BNF grammar then it is recursively enumerable.

Comment: Please explain me, why the `A Push Channel Protocol  (PCP)` is recursively enumerable? I can not see it.

Comment: What part of my previous comment is confusing you?

Comment: what does it mean `context-free languages`?

Comment: Recursively enumerable and context-free are both part of the Chomsky Hierarchy. You can easily google these terms.

Comment: Perhaps @zero_coding is confusing terms, and thinks "recursively enumerable" means that structures in the language can be (more or less) arbitrarily nested? For example, a string like this can likely be parsed by some regex, but a language like JSON where you can put objects in objects in objects would require a more complex parsing algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any tool, you should use a parser when it is suitable for the job. Turning strings into data structures is exactly what parsers are for.

This specific language *is* defined by a BNF and thus is also recursively enumerable (in fact, context-free) and so is a perfect candidate for parsing, but you can use a parser for all sorts of things. For example, log files may not have a defined BNF grammar but are often structured well enough in practice for parsing to be useful.